# Deep Belief Network with Denoising Auto Encoder in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder, dbn

I need to implement a classification application for neuron-signals. In the first step, I need to train a denoising autoencoder(DAE) layer for signal cleaning then, I will feed the output to a DBN network for classification. I tried to find support for these types in Tensorflow but all what I found was two models CNN and RNN. Does anyone has an idea about a robust implementation for these two models using Tensorflow?

Comment: I don't know about DBN (I too am searching for that) but Denoising Auto encoder are implemented in http://www.tflearn.org "Tflearn"

Comment: did u find the DBN implementation?